# Extract the common query path from RESTFUL URL (Ablate the resources) JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, express, restful-url

I have a RESTFUL url design like this: `GET /street/:streetName/house/:houseNumber` or `GET /street/:streetName/house/listings`. As you can see, the `:streetName` and `:houseNumber` are resource names. I am trying to extract the static (common) parts from the url for some following logics which means I want to get `/street/house` and `/street/house/listings` (**ablate all resources parts in the url**).

I was trying to find a JS lib for this but didn't find one. Any pointers?

PS: I can do some string matching to achieve this like split by "/" then concat them and only care about the key words, so I can ignore all resource names. But this doesn't seem robust.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a route for each URL pattern, you can set an additional property `req.staticParts` in each middleware:

```js
app.get("/street/:streetName/house/:houseNumber", function(req, res, next) {
  req.staticParts = "/street/house";
  ...
})
...
.get("/street/:streetName/house/:houseNumber/listings", function(req, res, next) {
  req.staticParts = "/street/house/listings";
  ...
})
.use(function(req, res) {
  additionalLogic(req.staticParts);
});
```

This avoids string operations and is very explicit, therefore very robust.

Parsing the URL into `staticParts` without knowledge of the routes is problematic. For example, parsing the URL `/street/house/25` based on keywords would lead to `req.staticParts = "/street/house"`, but there is no matching route for it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think in this way it's more like a switch function that get all static parts out for each cases and store them into a variable req.staticParts. 
I am wondering if there is a way I can send the URL into a parser then, the parser can output every parts, so I can assemble them easily.

Comment: See my augmented answer.